# Consume OData on Express.js Promise Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, odata

I am setting up a React backend server that I need to get data from an OData server.

I have installed the `o.js` package and I am following their startup guide https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata.

However, I am getting an error using the code they have provided.

`TypeError: o(...).get(...).then is not a function`

Here is my index.js on the Express server

```
const express = require("express");
const o = require('odata').o;

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const app = express();

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Hello from server!" });
});

app.get("/odata", (req, res) => {

    o('https://localhost:44335/odata')
        .get('OpenTask')
        .then((data) => console.log(data));

    res.json({ message: "odata" });
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

The line `o('https://localhost:44335/odata')` is what is throwing the error and what is on the o.js site.

The OData service is working, as I am able to connect to it on Postman.

Why is the promise error happening?

Comment: It seems that, despite [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata#usage-in-node), `get` doesn't return a [thenable](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-7). Very odd. I suggest saving what it does return to a variable, putting a breakpoint on it, and seeing what it is instead.

Comment: Once you solve that problem, the next problem that seems like it'll come up is that you seem to be calling `res.json` too early in the `/odata` handler. Presumably you want to use the data you get from `o` to send that reply. If so, the call to `res.json` has to be *inside* the `then` handler. (Separately: Be sure to handle promise rejection, too.)

Comment: Yes I know the response is in the wrong spot, I just wanted it to return something while I test the connection. Since my OData server is running on my machine I have a break point on it to know that I've hit it. Once it actually hits the endpoint I'll update the code.

Comment: I was able to get to the next error, the issue with their documentation is that you need to include `.query()` and a `catch()` in the request.